# find option by array value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have problem with finding option in select menu by array value.

```js
var array = ["task1", "task2"]
var select = document.getElementsByTagName('select');
for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  $(select).find('option[value=array[i]]').attr('selected', 'selected');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select">
  <option value="task1">task1</option>
  <option value="task2">task2</option>
</select>
```

Upper code returns error:

```
unrecognized expression: option[value=array[i]]
```

When i put string instead of array[i] everything is working.

How to make this work?

Comment: You need to choose a Tag Name with an index.

Comment: Why don't you create an object / map which is keyed by the option text ?  Then use the text to loop lookup the value, e.g. {"task1":"....", "task2":"...."}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three things you need to change.

1. `$('select').first();` → You need to capture only ONE element.
2. `'option[value="' + array[i] + '"]'` → You need concatenate the string.
3. `array.length` → Use this instead of the magic number "2"

```js
let array = [ "task1", "task2" ];
let $select = $('select').first();
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  $select.find('option[value="' + array[i] + '"]').attr('selected', 'selected');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select">
  <option value="task1">task1</option>
  <option value="task2">task2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank You :), this also solve problem with array values separated with spaces

Answer (score 3):

You need to make sure that the `array[i]` is a variable injected into the string - at the moment jQuery is seeing `'option[value=array[i]]'` and treating the whole thing as a string. Using `'option[value='+array[i]+']'` will inject your variable containing the relevant value into the string instead.

```js
var array = ["task1", "task2"]
var select = document.getElementsByTagName('select');
for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  $(select).find('option[value='+array[i]+']').attr('selected', 'selected');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select">
  <option value="task1">task1</option>
  <option value="task2">task2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: `.prop()` should be used to set the properties instead of `.attr()`

Comment: @Dana Ciocan Thank You, that solve the problem, but i chose Mr. Polywhirl solution which also solves space separated array values

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi happy to help and totally understand :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`.val(value)`](https://api.jquery.com/val/#val2) to set the value of `<select>` element.

Additionally, if you want to set multiple values then specify  `multiple` attribute with the element, [`.val(value)`](https://api.jquery.com/val/#val2) will work for both scenario

```js
var array = ["task1", "task2"]
$('select').val(array);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h3>Single: </h3>
<select>
  <option value="task1">task1</option>
  <option value="task2">task2</option>
</select>

<h3>Multiple: </h3>
<select multiple>
  <option value="task1">task1</option>
  <option value="task2">task2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wow, what a flood of new answers. I will probably delete mine in time. Just one point I noticed: if you want to be able to select multiple values, you need to provide the `multiple` attribute in your `<select>` element.

```js
var array = ["task1", "task2"];
var sel=$('select');
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) 
 { $('option[value='+array[i]+']', sel).attr('selected', 'selected');}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select" multiple>
  <option value="task1">task1</option>
  <option value="task2">task2</option>
  <option value="task3">task3</option>
</select>
```